# The thing in image... flowers garland

Tags: vocabulary

**What do we call the thing in the image in English?**

[image]

In South Asia, this is called Sehra... Of course, we don't see this in all cultures. What can we name it?

```
Face-garland

Face flowers-wreath
```

Comment: A Sehra (Bengali: শেহরি, Hindi: सेहरा, Urdu: سہرا) is a **headdress** worn by the groom during Indian, Pakistani and Bangladeshi weddings. This decorative groom’s **veil** can be **made either out of flowers or beads** and is tied to the groom’s turban or Pagdi. (Wikipedia)

Comment: It doesn't exist in 'Western' culture, so we would either have to use the Asian name or call it something like a 'bridegroom's floral veil'. (It isn't a wreath, because they are circular.)

Comment: @KateBunting - and who would wear a wreath at their own wedding?

Comment: @KateBunting - if I could have foreseen the future I might have worn one at my first wedding.

Comment: To clarify: Michael is referring to the fact that wreaths are often associated with funerals, though in fact they are used for other decorative purposes. Cambridge Dictionary gives as one of its examples "The bride wore a veil with a wreath of silk flowers."